# count "empty space" right/left in a 2D vector efficiently

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have a grid of the form `std::vector< vector<int> > grid (rows, std::vector<double>(columns));` which is a member variable of a class. The grid has stored values from the set {0,1,2, ... , 9}. Imagine if I go through the grid and at every position where `grid[row][col] != 0` I need to know how many zeros are to the left and to the right before again `grid[newRow][newCol] != 0` is fulfilled (to the left/right means in this row, so one has to iterate through the column index). For the moment I do it with the following two functions:

```
int countLeft(unsigned int rowIndex, unsigned int colIndex) {
    int left = 0;
    for (signed int i = colIndex-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (this->grid[rowIndex][colIndex] != 0 && this->grid[rowIndex][i] == 0){
            left++; 
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    return left;
}

int countRight(unsigned int rowIndex, unsigned int colIndex){
    int right = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = colIndex + 1; i < this->grid[0].size(); i++) {
        if (this->grid[rowIndex][i] == 0 && this->grid[rowIndex][colIndex] != 0) {
            right++;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    return right;
}
```

Running the Performance wizard on VS2013 I found out that these two functions are slowing down my program significantly. Therefore my question, how I could improve my method of knowing the zeros to the left/right, without counting every time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you timing a release version, or a debug version of your program?

Comment: How often do you update the grid?

Comment: Since it is part of a monte carlo simulation it gets updated several hundert thousand times

Comment: The test `this->grid[rowIndex][colIndex] != 0` done in both functions is constant inside the function, so just move it out to the begining of the function. If the compiler didn't already realised this for you, then you should see some improvement. Perhaps this simplification will allow the compiler to optimize a little better the loop also.

Comment: @André Sassi Thanks for your advise, but it did not affect the speed of the programm. So if anyone has a suggestion, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to store the result local and just calculate it when vector has changed. A setter for the vector would be a great place for the calulation. But this just helps when the vector doesn't update before every function call.